# How do i change the background color of "ng-block-ui" in angular 8?

Tags: angular8

ng-block-ui can be found here . 
https://github.com/kuuurt13/ng-block-ui .
I have tried inline styling and template references but it didnt worked out. 
live demo : https://stackblitz.com/github/kuuurt13/ng-block-ui/tree/master/examples/default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```css
:host ::ng-deep .block-ui-wrapper{
    background: black !important;
}
```